# SharePoint 2013 - SQL Server Reporting Services Service Application Error

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, reporting-services

I have 2-tier architecture i.e. SharePoint 2013 and SQL 2012 servers. I have configured the SSRS in SharePoint mode from SQL 2012 SP1 in the SharePoint server by following [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/install-the-first-report-server-in-sharepoint-mode?view=sql-server-2016&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2016https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fsql%2Freporting-services%2Finstall-windows%2Finstall-the-first-report-server-in-sharepoint-mode%3Fview%3Dsql-server-2016) link.

The SSRS reports are working desirably in the web application. But from today, I am facing issues while accessing the SSRS reporting pages:

> For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors

---

> An unexpected error occurred while connecting to the report server. 
>   Verify that the Reporting Services Service Application mapped to this
>   web application is available  OR the report server is available and
>   configured for SharePoint Integrated mode.

---

> An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for
>   more details. 
>   ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException:
>   An internal error occurred on the report server.  See the error log
>   for more details. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 
>   Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {BDEADF26-C265-11D0-BCED-00A0C90AB50F} failed due to the following
>   error:  800703fa Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that
>   has been marked for deletion. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703FA).

While checking the association of the SSRS application with web application/s, found below message:

> There are no web applications available to associate with this SQL
>   Server Reporting Services Service Application

I have checked everything and it was as per the Microsoft best practices.

Any help will be appreciated as I require to fix it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this error before in combination with other systems. One or both of the following solutions solved it:

**Solution 1:**

- Open the Group Policy editor (Gpedit.msc) on the affected server.
- Open the UserProfiles folder in the following path: Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > UserProfiles.
- Locate the Do not forcefully unload the user registry at user logoff setting.
- Change the setting to Enabled.
- Reference: [800703fa Illegal operation attempted ...](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3114011/800703fa-illegal-operation-attempted-on-a-registry-key-that-has-been-m)

**Solution 2:**

- Go to IIS Manager, select the Application Pool for your web application and click Advanced settings, change the value for "Load User Profile" to "true"
- Reference: [COM: Intermittent error 800703fa: Illegal Operation attempted on a registry key](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsnotes/2016/03/01/com-intermittent-error-800703fa-illegal-operation-attempted-on-a-registry-key/)
- Note: I have opened a Microsoft ticket to get confirmation that this IIS-change will be a supported one for a SharePoint WebApplication. This was confirmed.

Comment: I have applied both solutions. Can you please let me know the next step to do?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot provide any further steps. One or both above solution solved that problem for me if i had the error `800703fa Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion`.

Comment: Means you didn't need to perform any SSRS related configuration after executing the one or both the above solutions and your reports start working again as normal. Am I understood correctly?

Comment: I didn't have that error in context of SSRS. But i had it in some different scenarios (SecurityTokenService, UserProfileService). As the root-cause is always the same (user logoff in the background, HKCU registry-hive no longer accessible by application), i provided my answer.